# How to delete a child node of a parent with all their values in c# is just deleting child nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, removechild, removeall

Hello I'm trying to delete a child node of a parent node with all their values but only is removing the child values.

I have this:

```
 xmldoc.Load(XMLInterfacesFile);
 XmlNode RootToDelete = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("Servers/NEWINTERFACE");
 RootToDelete.RemoveAll();
 xmldoc.Save(XMLInterfacesFile);
```

My XML is :

```
<Servers>
  <NEWINTERFACE>
     <Host>10.10.10.2</Host>
     <Port>12</Port>
     <User>User</User>
  </NEWINTERFACE>
</Servers>
```

When I save the file my output is:

```
 <Servers>
  <NEWINTERFACE>
  </NEWINTERFACE>
</Servers>
```

I also want to delete element  but if I select a single node "Servers" it will delete everything inside of it If I have more than 1 servers...

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `RootToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(RootToDelete);`, that should do.